# Deriving a Django application from the Admin interface

Tags: django, django-admin

I am trying to make a Django application, using it for "Rapid Development". My application needs to list tables, and allow the user to view/add/modify (relation) data using forms. So essentially - 90% of my needs are accommodated by Django's *admin* interface.

Is there a way to base my application off of the admin interface, and then be able to customize it from there? It seems (going through the tutorial) that Django want's me to create all the HTML for the page layout, etc from scratch.

While I *can* do that - the whole reason I am looking to something like Django is to take care of the 90% standard database forms/tables that the admin interface does. Isn't there an easy way to use *this* as a higher-level framework to start working from, or do it all manually? Am I totally missing something here??

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to do a lot in the admin, but some things become difficult or awkward working within its bounds.  Whether it would be useful as a framework for your application or not is dependent on the your requirements, so that part of your question isn't really answerable.

Most admin customizations work by fiddling with the `ModelAdmin` classes attached to your models.  Some basic information on the admins and customization [can be found in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/), but you may also find it helpful to ask more specific questions here if you run into stumbling blocks.

As far as basing your application off the admin goes, you can alway mount the admin at the root of your URLs and then use it for your entire application.